# The iPhone 6 disconnects when the battery is 12%

Tags: iphone, battery

The iPhone 6 disconnects when the battery is 12%. When I start charging it, it shows that the battery charge is 1%. Earlier I had to replace the battery because it had blown out and there was a severe problem with incorrect battery display. What could be the problem?

Comment: Disconnects from what?

Comment: When did you have to replace the battery? If the new one is still under warranty, take it back to Apple.

Comment: My phone is 6 years old and the warranty is over.

Comment: It shuts off when I use it and the battery drops to 12%

Comment: To understand you correctly: You can use your phone just like it should, however, when you reach 12% battery, it shuts off and when connecting to power it shows 1% although it just said 12%?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: What iOS is it running? What does Settings / Battery / Health say?

Comment: How long ago did you have the battery replaced? ("Earlier I had to replace the battery....")

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem with my 8 months old iPhone 6. Even I replaced the battery but still, the problem was occurring. In the last, I need to change my phone due to this specific reason.

Comment: "8 months old iPhone 6"? Do you mean 8 years?

Answer (score 0):

I would completely empty the battery and fully charge it again without interruption. So that the sensor for the battery charge status works properly again

Otherwise let Apple know

Comment: Thank you, I will try this method.